Не понимаю, почему работает этот код на kotlin
Есть простой код на kotlin:
fun repeat(
  times: Int,
  action: (Int) -> Unit           // [1]
) {
  for (index in 0 until times) {
    action(index)                 // [2]
  }
}

fun my(){
  println("xxx")
}

fun main() {
  repeat(3) { my() }
}

Объясните, почему main() печатает:
xxx
xxx
xxx

Ведь, вроде бы, функция repeat требует, чтобы последний lambda-параметр
принимал Int на вход, а у меня функция my определена вообще без параметров...

функция action: (Int) -> Unit  требует, чтобы вы в нее передали int и вы это делаете. то, что вы никак не используете индекс, который передали в строке  repeat(3) { index-> my() } это уже ваше право)

Спасибо, @Wlad. Более-менее понял.

my() не передается как action. action в вашем случае это { my() }.
Чтобы передать именно my() как action придется добавить параметр и передать ссылку на функцию.
fun my(i: Int){
    println("xxx - $i")
}

fun main() {
    repeat(3, ::my)
}

Вывод будет:
xxx - 0
xxx - 1
xxx - 2

